# What does "arguments" do in release:prepare?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to know what does "arguments" exactly do as **release:prepare** parameter and what should we set as a value for it?
I've checked the description for it on [release:prepare description](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments) , but I don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The release plugin may call Maven along the way, with different phases/targets/arguments specified. The `-Darguments` option is useful for passing arguments to those nested executions.

If you typed `mvn release:prepare -Dmy.var=xxx` then the `my.var` would be defined for the release plugin only, it wouldn't pass it to nested invocations of Maven.

[See an example here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/07/passing-d-arguments-along-to-release.html)