# How to remote debug tests when mvn release:perform

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I need to remote debug `mvn release:perform` when it runs surefire.
I tried:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005" release:perform
```

and

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" release:perform
```

But tests won't await for remote debug and just start.
What is the correct way to remote debug `mvn release:perform`?

Comment: You need to pass `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` inside a `-Darguments`, because the Release Plugin launches a forked process. Something like `mvn -Darguments"-Dmaven.surefire.debug='-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE'" release:perform`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328901/what-does-arguments-do-in-releaseprepare/12329418#12329418

Comment: @Tunaki thanks a lot! 

mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.surefire.debug='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005'"

worked. I actually tried -Darguments but didn't get that I had to put -Dmaven.surefire.debug inside a -Darguments.